# Como mostrar el contenido de una lista que viene con campos numericos en String en java?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

Tengo la siguiente lista, y le paso un find, el cual me regresa una lista de Registro Acceso

```
private List<RegistroAcceso> listRegistroAcceso;
       listRegistroAcceso = registroAccesoService.findRegistroAccesoByNuserid(cvePersona);
```

dentro de esa lista hay 3 campos: NREADERIDN, NEVENTIDN y NDATETIME, cada uno de ellos trae valores numericos, por ejemplo para el campo NREADERIDN, si los valores de ese campo son 52739, 52731 y 52733, entonces le corresponde el valor INDEPENDENCIA, pero si sus valores son 3320, y 3321, le corresponde INDEPENDENCIA1

por ejemplo para el campo NEVENTIDN , si su valor es 55, 40 y 41 entonces le corresponde EXITOSO, sino le corresponde ERRONEO
entonces quiero convertir esos valores numericos que traen los campos, en valores tipo String, y que pueda yo mostrar esa lista, pero con su valor en texto asi como en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo esta tabla, pero ahorita solo me muestra el valor de los campos en numerico

```html
<p:dialog header="Análisis de Registros" widgetVar="modalIntentos" modal="true" height="200" width="600px" appendTo="@(body)">
  <h:form>
    <p:dataTable styleClass="columns" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" var="biometrico" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listRegistroAcceso}">

      <p:column headerText="DISPOSITIVO" style="width:150px;">
        <h:outputText value="#{biometrico.nreaderidn}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="EVENTO" style="width:150px;">
        <h:outputText value="#{biometrico.neventidn}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="FECHA / HORA" style="width:150px;">
        <h:outputText value="#{biometrico.ndatetime}" />
      </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como le puedo hacer para mostar los datos en string en la tabla?

Comment: Quieres mostrar el valor en letras del integer que tienes en la tabla?

Comment: Así es , es que esos valores corresponden a un valor en string,pero así vienen de la  bd

Comment: Puedes revisar este link http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/05/convert-math-number-to-equivalent-readable-word-in-java-code-with-example.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es agregar a `RegistroAcceso` los `getters` que provean la lógica.

P. ej.

```
public String getDescEventId() {
   switch (this.getNeventidn()) {
      case "55":
      case "40":
         return "EXITOSO";
      default:
         return "ERRONEO";
   }
}
```

Y en el JSF

```
    <h:outputText value="#{biometrico.descEventId}" />
```

Otras alternativas:

- Desarrollar un conjunto de funciones JSTL que contengan la lógica de transformación; acabas teniendo algo como esto:

  ```
  <h:outputText value="#{funciones:descripcionEvento(biometrico.neventidn)}" />
  ```
- Si no quieres modificar `RegistroAcceso` crear una clase con los métodos necesarios, y para cada `RegistroAcceso` crear una instancia con sus datos de la nueva clase. Usar esta última clase para representar los datos.